# Accessing base class elements without breaking encapsulation

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix

I have created two classes A and B where B inherits from class A. As you can see, I have a vector in class A that is currently under the protected section of the class. I am unsure if using protected is bad practice?

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
public :
   A();
protected:
   std::vector <std::string> a;
};

class B : A
{
public :
   B();
void accessVector()
{
    a.size();
}
private:

};
```

Comment: Completely depends on your design, that is perfectly valid and useful sometimes. The `protected` keyword exists for a reason.

Comment: _"I am unsure if using protected is bad practice?"_ If it's bad practice depends on the (semantical) context.

Comment: In general case, you make members protected when you do not want objects/instances of classes (base or derived) to access those members. But this gets broken in case of friend class.

Answer (score 2):

When `A` makes a data member `a` protected, it is offering the following guarantee to all classes that derive from it:

"You may do anything you like to `a` without telling me. This includes appending to it, modifying its contents, removing items, sorting it, moving from it, moving to it and otherwise making its state undefined and/or unknowable to me".

Remember that anyone may create a class that derives from `A`.

For this reason, to all intents and purposes, a protected member *is a* public member, since a derived class may simply say the following:

```
public:
using A::a;
```

Starting here and working forward, you'll find that there are only two sensible use-cases for `protected`:

- When a base class defines a virtual member function that may need to be called from an overridden version of the same function in a derived class.
- When the base class wants to expose 'data as interface' to a derived class, but not to the world.